# Swift - Declare Struct in two different files

Tags: swift, struct

I just approached Swift and I'm encountering some problems...

I have a class which helps me to fetch some results

```
class ExpencesOperations {

struct ExpencesByDate {
    var day: String!
    var expence: [PFObject]
}

var expencesByDateArray = [ExpencesByDate]()

   func getExpencesByDate(expences: [PFObject]) ->  [ExpencesByDate] {
   .....  my function
          return expencesByDateArray
   }
}
```

When I call it in my TableViewController I don't know how to redeclare the struct ExpencesDate!

```
class HomeTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var myCurrency = MyCurrency()
var expencesOperations = ExpencesOperations()
var expencesByDateArray = [ExpencesOperations.ExpencesByDate]() /* Not Working */

func fetchExpences() {
   expencesByDateArray = self.expencesOperations.getExpencesByDate(someInput) /* here i get the error */
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Put the struct outside of your class scope and it should be visible to other files as well.

```
struct ExpencesByDate {
    var day: String!
    var expence: [PFObject]
}


class ExpencesOperations {

   var expencesByDateArray = [ExpencesByDate]()

   func getExpencesByDate(expences: [PFObject]) ->  [ExpencesByDate] {
   .....  my function
          return expencesByDateArray
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It was such a noob mistake!

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide arguments for proper initialization of the ExpencesByDate struct (I think you meant Expen**S**es, right?)

For example:

```
var expencesByDateArray = [ExpencesOperations.ExpencesByDate(day: "Friday", expence: [PFObject]())]
```

And regarding:

> ...getExpencesByDate(someInput) /* here i get the error */

The function you created expects an array:

```
func getExpencesByDate(expences: [PFObject]) -> [ExpencesByDate]
```

It's not clear from your question what `someInput` is. Is that an array?
As you posted in the question, it will always fail.

Plus, what are the compiler error messages?